# Mapping based on the value of one field in BizTalk orchestration maps

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-mapper

I am stuck in one situation in mapping from one message to another in BizTalk orchestration which I am not able to cross over. The scenario is as follows:
Source schema has many fields and destination schema have many child elements and the child fields of these destination elements can have one to one mapping with the source schema fields.

Suppose Source Schema has fields like as follows:

```
SF1 
SF2
SF3
SF4
SF5
```

and Destination schema contains following elements

```
DEL1 and DEL1 has fields DEL1_F1,DEL1_F2,DEL1_F3,DEL1_F4,DEL1_F5
DEL2 and DEL2 has fields DEL2_F1,DEL2_F2,DEL2_F3,DEL2_F4,DEL21_F5
DEL3 and DEL3 has fields DEL3_F1,DEL3_F2,DEL3_F3,DEL3_F4,DEL3_F5
```

Now Depending upon the value SF1 I need to map the value. If the value of SF1 is '0' then I will map the SF1 , SF2 ,SF3 , SF4 and SF5 with DEL1_F1,DEL1_F2,DEL1_F3,DEL1_F4,DEL1_F5 respectively and if the value of SF1 is '1' then I will map the SF1 , SF2 ,SF3 , SF4 and SF5 with DEL2_F1,DEL2_F2,DEL2_F3,DEL2_F4,DEL21_F5 and if the value of SF1 is '3' then the mapping of SF1 , SF2 ,SF3 , SF4 and SF5 needs to be done with DEL3_F1,DEL3_F2,DEL3_F3,DEL3_F4,DEL3_F5.

Please suggest me how can I achieve this in BizTalk mapping.

Comment: Have you considered using XSLT instead of the mapper? This approach would make this specific use case very easy by using the xsl:choose/xsl:when/wsl:otherwise statements.

Comment: It would be nice if you could add example schemas to the question and show what you have tried and why it is not working for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use builtin functoids provided by visual studio. [image]

Comment: I just want to avoid this much use of functoid. Using this aproach will take 4 functioids for one field mapping.

Comment: i think this is the only way you can do

Comment: That is only 2 functoids per field that isn't that much, the only other option is as per Pieter Vandenheede's comment and to use XSLT instead.